# Cloud hosting for windows domain controller, possible?

Tags: active-directory, cloud-hosting

We currently host our own domain controller (small company) locally on dedicated h/w. However to mitigate disaster we're considering the use of virtualisation and cloud hosting.

One thought is

Virtual primary domain controller hosted in the cloud + a local (secondary) virtualised server running in the office as a cache?

Is this possible or should I consider something else? We're happy to pay for the decent hosting and DR but this is really out of my experience.

Comment: There is no such thing as primary/secondary domain controllers. As for your question, it would probably be cheaper to have 2 domain controllers on-site and pay for some form of cloud backup. BTW, I'm pretty sure you don't want to be mitigating disaster recovery ;)

Comment: Lol - I meant mitigate disaster :-)

Comment: Acutally thee is. One domain controller is special (PDC Emulator) and serves s time source.OTher roles are also assigned to specific domain controllers. They are NOT all equal.

Comment: So can I virtualise the domain controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If security isn't a huge concern, I would recommend using Amazon's EC2 instance. If bandwidth is an issue, you could very easily use the /async switch for replication. [Joe Field has an excellent article on how to host Windows Domain in the Cloud](http://blog.joefield.co.uk/?p=25)

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could configure Samba as a domain controller under GNU/Linux. With the  advantage being that there are many cheap GNU/Linux Virtual Private Server (VPS) providers.

This topic interests me since I am looking to do the same thing for a windows network at a small office. I'll post back here if I find anything of interest.

Comment: Seems like a bad suggestion.  You can't do gpos from samba, and the older style would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: actually samba4 does support gpos. Not samba 3, though, maybe that is why you mentioned that :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using truestack direct connect- migrate the domain, remove the on-prem server and connect the clients directly to Windows domain in AWS.

Comment: You were too hurry? :) I have a [suggested read](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) for you